# Reference an Image in another project

Tags: android

I have an project that I put all of my images for the system in the workspace.
I have this at the top of my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:images="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.utas.android.imagelibrary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    android:padding="8dip"
    >
```

The namespace "images" gives a warning in Eclipse stating "unused names space images", which leads me to believe I am atleast doing that part right but the next part is wrong.

With in my ImageLibrary (a project that has the "Is Library" check boxed checked in the same workspace) I have the following pathing
**res/drawable/01_core_accept/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_acept.png**

I have a button within the layout as follows.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_finish_a"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_finish_a_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_start_c"
    android:icon="@images:res/drawable/01_core_accept/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_acept"
    android:onClick="finishActivityA"
    />
```

However I am getting an error on the image reference stating **"error:Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@images:res/drawable/01_core_accept/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_acept')."**

How do I properly reference an image in an external?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need this line:

```
xmlns:images="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.utas.android.imagelibrary"
```

The line should read:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_acept"
```

If you've linked an Android Library project correctly, resources defined in that library should be compiled into your app and you reference the same way as resources in your own res folders.

Comment: I guess I spoke to soon. The compiler did remove the error until I ran the application. In other words changing it and saving it acting like it saw the resource. But then when I ran it the error returned. Same error, but just new location. Any ideas?